# Using memberships perks on brand account

Tags: youtube

I have 1 Google Account, and since I wanted different images on Gmail and YouTube I created a brand channel.
I already had memberships before I created the brand account.

When I switch to the brand account I can see my memberships but the community tab doesn't show the "members only" posts or videos and I can't use emotes either.

Has anyone dealt with this before?